How to manage offline vector tiles in an ionic app?
I have an ionic - angular - capacitor app with a map, drawn by openlayers using vector tiles from different online sources (mapbox, tomtom or openstreetmap). I try to add the possibility to use a set of offline vector openstreetmap tiles (necat.mbtiles) that I copy to the Documents forlder of an android device.
After dealing with permissions, I try to open the mbtiles database, but I don't manage it:
      async openDatabase() {
        try {
          const path = await this.getDatabasePath();
          console.log(path);
          this.db = await this.sqlite.create({
            name: path,
            location: 'default',
          });
          console.log('Database opened successfully');
        } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error opening database', error);
      }
    }

I get the error Error opening database Error: Could not open database
The database path is OK. I reduced the geographic coverage of the database in order to lower the file size from 600 MB to 60MB, but the result is the same
